# How to sum column with invalid number data?

Tags: postgresql

I tried to sum **pyt_amaun** column but it failed because of invalid data.

[image: HG]

How can I solve this when using Postgres? I don't own the database so I cant reformat the data.

Query

```
select sum(pyt_amaun) as sum_pyt_amaun 
from compound_payments;
```

Error message

> ```
> Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
> LINE 1: select sum(pyt_amaun) as sum_pyt_amaun from >     compound_payments...
>                ^ 
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Comment: Another good example why storing numbers in a varchar columns is a **really**, really bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just after asking SO I straight got the solution, so here it is

```
select sum(cast(pyt_amaun as double precision)) as sum_pyt_amaun from compound_payments;
```